# Quality Control in SPS data in R

Tags: r

I have a big dataset with SNPs (genotypes) which is 501 rows and 42844 columns.

The data is like that :

```
 OAR19_64675012.1 OAR19_64803054.1 OAR1_88143.1 s09912.1 s36301.1 s34880.1
           AB               AB           BB       BB       AA       AA
           AB               AB           AB       AA       AB       AB
           AB               AB           BB       AB       BB       AA
           AA               BB           BB       AB       AA       AA
```

I have a big problem in the QC process.
I'm using the QCGWAS library in R and when I'm hitting the command in order to start Quality Control:

```
  headers<- names(snp) ## names of the columns, snp is the dataframe above

  # make them as a dataframe with characters
  h_data<- as.character(data.frame(headers , stringsAsFactors = F))


new_data <- QC_GWAS(filename = "data1.txt",   # command for QC data1.txt is my snps data 
                 header_translations = h_data,
                 save_final_dataset = TRUE)
```

I'm getting an this Error :

```
Error: file.exists(paste(dir_references, header_translations, sep = "/")) is not TRUE
```

I don't know what i have to do.... I'm searching things but i'm getting errors all the time... I try to follow the quick start guide in /R/library/QCGWAS/doc but i'm getting Errors.

Please if anyone has an idea and some time to help me i would apreceate that. It is very significant for me to solve this problem in order to continue the project. I've used some other libraries but I couldn't handle the quality control because they didn't give me clean data.

Comment: Are we supposed to assume that loading the QCGWAS _package_ will make the `data1.txt` file available in our working directory? (That would be most unusual if it were true.) Seems unclear to me what `# command for QC data1.txt is my snps data`  is supposed to tell us.

Comment: ok i don't understand what I have to do.... I have a dataset in my working directory which is data1.txt with my snps, so this is my input file. From those that i understand from the documentation of QCGWAS is that in the above command we put the input file (data1.txt) and it will apply the process of Quality Control into this data, and then it will create a new dataset in the same working directory with the clean data. I'm not sure if i have understood well. However , is any chat here to speak with you because i think that you are very experienced and you can help me.

Comment: @Spacedman , Yes you are true... the traceback() gives me three things   :> traceback()
3: stop(sprintf(ngettext(length(r), "%s is not TRUE", "%s are not all TRUE"), 
       ch), call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
2: stopifnot(is.character(header_translations), nchar(header_translations) > 2L, file.exists(paste(dir_references, header_translations, 
       sep = "/")))
1: QC_GWAS(filename = "snps.txt", header_translations = h_data, 
       save_final_dataset = TRUE)